# Set width 100% for landscape orientation

Tags: html, css

My website has white empty space on the right side, on a iphone for landscape (on Chrome). I tried adding this in the head section(but its not helping):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

wrapper has 100% width
for portrain it's ok, but foe landscape appear white space
attach sreenshots
[image]

Comment: Could there possibly be over-flow? `max-width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;`

Comment: Could you paste a code example? There are sooooo many possibilities but we need a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that you have an overflowing element on the right side. Maybe a fly-out navigation, or maybe just an errant element. If you can SCROLL horizontally to it, there's a great chance that this is your issue.

If you are having trouble finding it, try Firefox's 3d view. I use that junk all of the time to find those sneaky overflowing elements.

Comment: all elements are in wrapper

Comment: Wow, dowvotes for trying to help. This place is really hit or miss. . . 

@ргдшщ - post a demo or EXPECT people to assume things about your picture.